# Reading serial output from Arduino on LabVIEW using LINX

Tags: arduino, labview

I have written an Arduino code that has a float serial output. I am trying to send this float variable from Arduino to LabVIEW using LINX for some algorithm calculation. Would appreciate help on using LabVIEW LINX to read the serial output from the Arduino.

I have tried using the visa read block but whenever i try to join the visa read block with the LINX open serial block, there is an error due to LINX resource not being able to link to visa resource.

Is there an alternative for Visa Read block for LINX?

Answer (score 1):

Linx library contains functions to read data from Arduino board. You don't need to use "raw" function `VISA Read` - and you can't connect it to Linx library functions because inputs/outputs of VIs have different data types.

In order to read analog value from Arduino board, you need to use `Analog Read 1 Chan.vi` from Linx pallete. Take a look on examples in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW XXXX\examples\MakerHub\LINX\` - hope it will help you to get into the library.

Comment: i did saw that channel. however the issue is that i am not reading analog value from a channel. this is because the analog value that i want to read from arduino is a calculation from the result from 2 analog channels on the arduino board.

Comment: But how do you send that data? Do you send it by UART? If so, there are functions also for UART reading, under LINX -> Peripherals -> UART functions pallete.